# Integration of a $BV$ function with respect to a finite, signed Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, bounded-variation

Let $u,w\in BV(0,1)$ be given. Since we are in dimension 1 $u$ is continuous almost everywhere and has a representation $u^{l}$ and $u^{r}$ (left, right hand side continuous). Thus we can consider the convex combination 
$$
\delta u^{l}(x)+(1-\delta)u^{r}(x)
$$
for $\delta\in[0,1]$ and $x\in[0,1]$.

Furthermore the derivative of $w$ is a finite signed Radon measure and I ask myself if we can define the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}u(x)\ dw'(\cdot)(x).
$$
In general this is not possible for $u\in BV(0,1)$ since we must be able to evaluate $u$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. That is why I came up with the following definition, which depends on the convex combination stated above:
$$
\delta\bullet\int_{0}^{1}u(x)\ dw'(\cdot)(x):=\int_{0}^{1} \delta u^{l}(x)+(1-\delta)u^{r}(x)\ dw'(\cdot)(x)
$$
Is this expression well defined? Of course for the dirac part of $w'$ as well as the Lebesgue part there is no problem. But I do not know enough of the Cantor part of $w'$ to conclude that the $\delta\bullet\int$ is well defined, and my knowledge about measure theory seems unsufficient :-(!
I am thankful for every hint or comment and thank You very much in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the derivative of $w$ is a finite signed Radon measure

Not really. The derivative *induces* a finite signed Radon measure, but it has more structure than the measure. Consider two functions 
$$w_1(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \quad & x\le 0 \\ 1, \quad &x>0 \end{cases}$$
$$w_2(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \quad & x<0 \\  1, \quad &x\ge 0 \end{cases}$$
The corresponding Radon measures are the same: Dirac delta at $0$, because integration against either $dw_j$ gives the same result for *continuous* functions. But an attempt to integrate discontinuous functions reveals the difference: $\int f\,dw_1$ is defined when $f(0+)=f(0)$, while $\int f\,dw_2$ is defined when $f(0-)=f(0)$. BV functions behave like every point has "left half" and "right half": $dw_1$ puts its weight on the right half of $0$, while $dw_2$ puts its weight on the left.

> we must be able to evaluate $u$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

If $u$ is a bounded variation function on $[0,1]$, then it is a *function*, and functions can be evaluated at any point of their domain. Do you consider BV as a space of equivalence classes like $L^1$? (I don't.)

Anyway: you can integrate any bounded Borel measurable function $f$ with respect to any finite signed Radon measure $\mu$. The construction is standard: split $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ into positive and negative parts. The integrals $\int f\,d\mu^+$  and $\int f\,d\mu^-$ are standard Lebesgue integrals, and both are finite.

But if $u$ is not really a function (and $w'$ is not really a Radon measure), then we have to get creative.

> I do not know enough of the Cantor part of $w'$

Never mind the Cantor part. The set of discontinuities of $u$ is at most countable, and therefore the issues of "representative" of $u$ do not affect integration with respect to the Cantor part of $w'$.  The jumps of $w$ are the only problem, and one may have to worry about left vs right jumps, as I noted above.

The following looks most natural to me: both integrals $\int u^l\,dw^r$ and $\int u^r\,dw^l$ make sense for any BV functions $u,w$. You can define the integral to be $$\delta \int u^l\,dw^r+(1-\delta)\int u^r\,dw^l $$

Comment: Thank You very much. I was imprecise about the Definition of $BV$ functions. Actually I do not use the point-wise definition but the a.e Definition. There are results that state, we can find for any $BV$ function a pointwise representation as You already mentioned. So I wrote "we must be able to evaluate $u$..." I am stucked at your possible definition of the $\delta$-integral. Why do You use the right and left continuous part for the measure, that is $dw^{l},\ dw^{r}$. I thought this would make no difference....and would coincide with my Definition?

Comment: @Alex We probably also use different definitions of the integral with respect to $dw$. I used Riemann-Stiltjes integral, as defined in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. If you use  Lebesgue integral, then a representative of $w$ indeed does not matter. You just pick a representative for $u$, such as one of those convex combinations, and integrate it according to the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think you are right. In any case you helped me a lot...!